# Windows Terminal keybindings commands list

Tags: windows-terminal

There is a new Windows Terminal out there and I want to configure a few key bindings in it like so:

```
  "keybindings":
  [
    ...
    {
      "command": "<command>",
      "keys": ["<keys>"]
    }
    ...
  ]
```

This procedure is described on [Custom key bindings in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings), but it doesn't list all commands!

Do you know where can I get the full list?

Comment: [Windows Terminal Key Bindings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I have literally included this link in the question, because it seems that the page does not list all of the possible commands.

Comment: Well that page has a lot. Only Microsoft can tell you what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Windows Terminal being open source, we can directly look up the available commands in the Windows Terminal's [code](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/b8e36bae9f869c56caa56c1f9f6b071dac796d33/src/cascadia/TerminalSettingsModel/ActionAndArgs.cpp)! I took the liberty to list them for you here:

```
adjustFontSize
closeOtherTabs
closePane
closeTab
closeTabsAfter
closeWindow
copy
duplicateTab
wt
find
moveFocus
newTab
nextTab
openNewTabDropdown
openSettings
openTabColorPicker
paste
prevTab
renameTab
openTabRenamer
resetFontSize
resizePane
scrollDown
scrollDownPage
scrollUp
scrollUpPage
scrollToTop
scrollToBottom
sendInput
setColorScheme
setTabColor
splitPane
switchToTab
tabSearch
toggleAlwaysOnTop
commandPalette
toggleFocusMode
toggleFullscreen
togglePaneZoom
toggleRetroEffect
toggleShaderEffects
moveTab
breakIntoDebugger
findMatch
toggleReadOnlyMode
newWindow
identifyWindow
identifyWindows
renameWindow
openWindowRenamer
action
```

Note that the file also lists the command `unbound`, but this is a placeholder used to remove keybindings. There does appear to be a few commands here that aren't listed in the documentation. One of which is `identifyWindow` which displays the name and ID of the current window in a tooltip.